# AddressAlreadyInUseException when starting azure project locally

Tags: azure, localhost, iis-express

Since I restarted my computer yesterday I cant start any of my azure cloud projects due to this error :-

> System.ServiceModel.AddressAlreadyInUseException: Cannot listen on
>   pipe name 'net.pipe://localhost/dfService/' because another pipe
>   endpoint is already listening on that name. --->
>   System.IO.PipeException: Cannot listen on pipe name
>   'net.pipe://localhost/dfService/' because another pipe endpoint is
>   already listening on that name.

I've checked the project ports and there all no standard ports that shouldn't and haven't conflicted with anything.

In a last ditch attempt I formatted my machine as I didnt have much on anyway and even with a clean install of VS2013, Azure SDK 2.6 and Windows 8.1 Im still getting the same error.

Has anybody has similiar problems or could suggest a direction for me to go in?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It helped me to shutdown both *Computing* and *Storage Emulator*, close *Azure Simulation Monitor* (`csmonitor.exe` systray application) and **manually start the Azure Emulator as an administrator**. Also if it started the *Emulator Express* and you need *Full Emulator* (I expect so, since this error didn't appear with the *Express* for me), just stop it and start the *Full Emulator* using systray icon.

Just don't let Visual Studio to start it automatically. I don't know what was the real reason of that error, but this solved it for me.